# Creating a Compact "WHERE" Filter in SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have a long list ( or a table of 3 to 4 columns of data) which simultaneously needs to be satisfied in a query, like below:

```
A    B   C
x1   y1  z1
x2   y2   z2
x3   y3   z3
.
.
.
xn    yn   zn
```

Is there a way I can create an expression/function etc or separate list etc which I can have  which can be called into the SQL Query (instead of explicitly writing it):

So assuming, I have this list as a matrix/list in a table X and I can use

and I can use a sample SQL query something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE B
WHERE CONDITION  IN  ROWS OF TABLE X
```

Just to add here, that I am using python driver to get data via database and the table X which I have is which I created locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM TABLE B
WHERE (b.a, b.b, b.c) IN (SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c FROM X)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon... But where does does table X has to be? I forgot to mention, that table X is one which I have created and not in the database.

Comment: Also just to add, I am using a python engine(pyodbc) to pull data from the database, so you may help me in saying where in that python file (or separate file), I can keep the table or datframe X?